# How can i keep the user logged in?

Tags: flutter

Here's my scenario:

A user signs up to the app by simply choosing a username that's not taken and putting a pass
When the user signs in to the app, his userID (primary key of user in my database) is stored locally and is used for all my services.

I am using SQL server for the database.

What i am trying to accomplish is that once a user signs in. I want to keep him signed in but i don't know how since once the app starts up again after being closed, userid won't even be initialized (until the user logs in) so I can't know which user should i sign in automatically in the app.
How can i get around this (i prefer to do this from the frontend side if possible, if not then how can i do it backend wise?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter

Comment: Yes this seems like it's exactly the same as my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared preferences to save the user ID, because you are using an SQL Server DB perhaps you will provide also a token and need to store the token too.

On the first login of the user save the data after the login is done successfully.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

 var _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  /// Method that saves the token (if you need the token) and userID in Shared Preferences
  /// ----------------------------------------------------------
  Future<bool> _setMobileToken(String token , String username, String userID) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString("username", username);
    prefs.setString("userID", userID);
    return prefs.setString(_storageKeyMobileToken, token);
  }
```

After that when you close the app and open in again you just need to read your data from Shared Preferences.

```
    // Async function that calls getSharedPreferences
  awaitSharedPref() async {
    await getSharedPreferences();
  }


  // Get the username and token from SharedPreferences and check if the token is valid
  awaitToken() async {
    await functions.getMobileToken();

    if (token != "" && token != null && username!= "" && username!= null ) {

        // If you use any token try to make a validation if was expired or not 
        //_presenter.validateToken(token, username.toString());

        // If not redirect the user directly on the home page 
        Navigator.of(_ctx).pushReplacementNamed("/home");

    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/login");
    }

  }
```

If you want you can also add a "Remember me" checkbox, so even if he log out from the app the next time he will open it, can click directly the "Login" button with username and pass autocomplete.

```
    final rememberMe = CheckboxListTile(
  value: checkValue,
  onChanged: _onChanged,
  title: new Text("Remember me", style: new TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[600], fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
);


_onChanged(bool value) async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      checkValue = value;
      sharedPreferences.setBool("check", checkValue);
      sharedPreferences.setString("username", username.text);
      sharedPreferences.setString("password", password.text);
      getCredential();
    });
}
```

Comment: Poorly answered, Please provide proper explanations as to how you define methods and variables