# Flutter Onboarding Screen only one time

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter and dart and i am trying to make an app with an onboarding screen with 3 pages and i am trying to skip the onboarding screen when the user has already opened the app once. I have seen something similar with the shared preferences, but i couldn't make it work.

This is my onboarding screen:

```
    class OnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreenState createState() => _OnboardingScreenState();
}

class _OnboardingScreenState extends State<OnboardingScreen> {

  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF3594DD),
                Color(0xFF4563DB),
                Color(0xFF5036D5),
                Color(0xFF5B16D0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => print('Skip'),
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome to ...',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print('Get Started'),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get Started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to se a value when the first Screen is see. In the main you can load this value and use it to decide where to route the user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` in `main()`
And set a `initScreen` variable when first time init, set to 1 to indicate it has initialized 
And In `MyApp initialRoute` check `initScreen` is `null` to decide which route to go 
You can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
int initScreen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  initScreen = await prefs.getInt("initScreen");
  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);
  print('initScreen ${initScreen}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null ? "first" : "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: "demo",
            ),
        "first": (context) => OnboardingScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

int initScreen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  initScreen = await prefs.getInt("initScreen");
  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);
  print('initScreen ${initScreen}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null ? "first" : "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: "demo",
            ),
        "first": (context) => OnboardingScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreenState createState() => _OnboardingScreenState();
}

class _OnboardingScreenState extends State<OnboardingScreen> {
  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF3594DD),
                Color(0xFF4563DB),
                Color(0xFF5036D5),
                Color(0xFF5B16D0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => print('Skip'),
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome to ...',
                              //style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              //style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              //style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              //style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/lorem_Ipsum.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              //style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'lorem Ipsum',
                              //style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print('Get Started'),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get Started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. If he doesn't want to setup a route he can also do... home: initScreen ? OnboardingScreen() : MyHomePage(),

Comment: How to get Shared_Preferences?

Comment: You have to install the pub, @LunLeong: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Another thought would be to set the initScreen after the user has actually seen all the onboarding. Also to make it more clear, it could be a boolean, not an integer. And it could be called "hasSeenOnboarding". I am not quite sure wether it is a good option to wait for shared preferences on every app start. Any experience with how long it takes?

Answer (score 1):

Most times you will need to go from onboarding to login to mainscreen

```js
class OnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  OnboardingScreen({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  State < OnboardingScreen > createState() => _onboardingScreenState();
}

class _onboardingScreenState extends State < OnboardingScreen > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            IsFirstTime().once(1);

            //navigate
          },
          child: Text('Login screen something')),
      ));
  }
}
```

```html
onbo
```

```js
class login extends StatefulWidget {
  login({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  State < login > createState() => _loginState();
}

class _loginState extends State < login > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            IsFirstTime().once(2);
            //navigate to mainscreen
          },
          child: Text('Login screen something')),
      ));
  }
}
```

```js
Future < void > main() async {

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // transparent status bar
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark // dark text for status bar
    ));
    //get stored int from sharedpref
    Future < int > alreadyAUser = IsFirstTime().getOnce();

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: AppProviders.providers,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: AppRoutes.routes(),
        home: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            // Checking if future is resolved or not
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If data is present
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final data = snapshot.data as int;
                print(data);
                switch (data) {
                  case 0:
                    return OnboardingScreen();

                  case 1:
                    return LoginScreen();

                  case 2:
                    return MainScreen();
                }

                // if we got our data
              }
            }

            // Displaying blank to indicate waiting state
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            );
          },

          // Future that needs to be resolved
          // inorder to display something on the Canvas
          future: alreadyAUser,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-->

```
class IsFirstTime {
  Future < int > getOnce() async {
    int ? intValue;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String

    if (prefs.getInt("initScreen") == null) {
      intValue = 0;
    } else {
      intValue = prefs.getInt("initScreen");
    }

    return intValue!;
  }

  Future once(int num) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //initScreen
    await prefs.setInt("initScreen", num);

    int initScreen = (prefs.getInt("initScreen")) !;
    print('initScreen ${initScreen}');
    // return initScreen;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using GETX, in order to make it show only once; you will need to modify only in **main()** which in turn will have to have the **async** property.

You need to install these two libraries in case you want to handle it with GETX in pubspec.yaml [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) & [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
sdk: flutter
# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
google_fonts: ^6.1.0
shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
 get_storage: ^2.1.1

dev_dependencies:
 get: any
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
```

Once you have installed those dependencies in the pubspec.yaml , in your main class you will import the libraries and add the following code to your method

Inside the main method you will have to attach these lines:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/pages/HomeV2.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/view/home/home.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/view/login/login_page.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/view/intro/onboarding_page.dart';
import 'package:Test_project/view/register/register_page.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 int? initScreen = prefs.getInt("initScreen");

 if (initScreen == null) {
  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);
 }

   runApp(MyApp(initScreen: initScreen));
 }
```

The most important imports are:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

And the implementation would be as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 final int? initScreen;

 const MyApp({Key? key, required this.initScreen}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Test_project',
       // In this line you define the Onboarding window and in case it has been 
        //previously deployed it goes directly to the home view.           
      initialRoute: initScreen == null || initScreen == 0 ? '/' : '/login',
      getPages: [
      GetPage(name: '/', page: () => OnboardingPage()),
      GetPage(name: '/login', page: 
              ()=>LoginPage(controller:Home_controller())),
      GetPage(name: '/home', page: () => HomeV2()),
      GetPage(name: '/register', page: () => RegisterPage()),
       ],
      theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      useMaterial3: true,
       ),
     navigatorKey: Get.key,
         );
        }
      }
```

If you have any questions, attach your commentary :)

- Eng. Emmanuel A. Ruiz García