# How to add onboarding screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey i started to learn about flutter, and i decide to make full app. But first i want to create onboarding screen after installing the app, but when the user close the app and open it again it will not displaying onboarding screen but straight to the homescreen. Does anyone know how to do it? maybe a link to tutorial or something that would be helpful. thanks

Comment: If you want help with your code you need to show us your code with a problem. StackOverflow is not google or a coding service. Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are looking for an easy way to store simple values on the device, as it appears to be your case, check the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package.

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugins and online tutorials that will help you, i have listed some of them below :

1) basic onboarding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eRQyE2PN7w

2) Intermediate level :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0S8H5opbG4

Some documneted tuts:

1) https://medium.com/@xsokev/onboarding-exercise-a584ebd9f608

2) https://uiflutter.com/ui/an-example-of-onboarding-screen-on-flutter.html

or check out this stackoverflow answer :

[Flutter Onboarding Screen only one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241566/flutter-onboarding-screen-only-one-time)