# Flutter : Keep User Login with SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i have some problem with [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). How to keep users Login though app close ?

I already storing username with this code :

```
setState(() {
        preferences.setString('token', dataUser[0]['username']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            PageTransition(
                type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                child: HomePage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
```

When i clik button login , it's working go to HomePage. To ensure the username is storing/not, I make function to get my token and fetch that token.

My token fetch what i expect with this code :

```
String checkPref;
  getPrefIdUser() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      checkPref = sharedPreferences.getString('token');
      if (checkPref == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            PageTransition(
                type: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
                child: LoginPage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      } else {
        // Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        //     PageTransition(
        //         type: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
        //         child: HomePage()),
        //     (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    });
  }
```

I Already put `getPrefIdUser()` in initState like this in my HomePage:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPrefIdUser();
  }
```

Problem is, when i restart my app (i try in real device) users back to Login page again. I don't know the problem it's.

Can you help me with this problem . Thanks.

> It's My Button Login Function

```
void _loginMahasiswa() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final body = {"email": _txtEmail.text, "password": _txtPassword.text};
    var loginMahasiswa = await api.loginMahasiswa(body);
    String message = loginMahasiswa['message'];
    var dataUser = loginMahasiswa['data'];

    if (loginMahasiswa['status'] == true) {

      setState(() {
        preferences.setString('token', dataUser[0]['username']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            PageTransition(
                type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                child: HomePage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
    } else {
      print(message);
      _showSnackBar(context, message, Colors.red);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to call setString in setState(). Try using await when you are calling setString method.

Comment: @CanTaşpınar sorry, can you explain that ? i dont get it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this check in main function directly

```
Future<void> main() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');
  print(token);

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: token == null ? Login() : Home()));
}
```

also reference this too [How to use shared preferences to keep user logged in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter/54382116)

Comment: `Future<void> main() async` no need to declaration in initstate ? or this Future immediately work ?

Comment: This syntax is  needed for async await because SharedPreferences.getInstance need await. Most of the time, we use this syntax void main() => runApp(MyApp());  In you case, check SharedPreferences then decide start HomePage for LoginPage.

Comment: I'm already try that code and change little,But when i hot restart i go to LoginPage even though i can see the token not null in terminal. I'm mistake something ? 
It's my full code HomePage if you need . https://pastebin.com/5PLhkwSL

Comment: you did it in wrong way. please replace void main() => runApp(Welcome()); with new code. and you don't have to  call  main() in InitState

Comment: flutter app entry point is main() not HomePage. you have to remove duplicate main in HomePage too.

Comment: This solution works when you don't need to add a provider to your app but, what if you need to do it? I need to call to MyApp (statelessWidget) to wrapper it with a provider. This solution doesn't work for all use cases.