# How to login and Signup with Rest API using flutter with Session establishment

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created a login form with email, password a login button. I am new to flutter, dart and web.

How do I integrate the JSON Restfull API for Login and Signup, by using JSON as an object.

Also please let me know how to establish a session once the user is logged in.

Please let me know how to Skip Login Page if the user has already logged in (by using Flutter and Dart)

I have created the login screen and the Signup screen, also the Splash screen

```js
//Splash Screen UI Code:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:interview/myhomepage.dart';
import 'package:interview/signup.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
);

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      vsync: this,
    );

    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  final background = Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.jpg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
  final greenOpacity = Container(
    color: Color(0xAA72F1CF),
  );

  Widget button(String lable, Function onTap) {
    return new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: new SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, -0.6), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(controller),
        child: Material(
          color: Color(0xBB00D699),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            splashColor: Colors.white24,
            highlightColor: Colors.white10,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  lable,
                  style: textStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

    final logo = new ScaleTransition(
      scale: animation,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/logo.png',
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
      ),
    );

    final description = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: new SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, -0.8), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(controller),
        child: Text(
          'The interviewee social network.',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: textStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final separator = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              'OR',
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          ),
          Container(width: 20.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final signWith = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Sign in with',
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('google');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Google',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Color(0xFFE65100),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(' or', style: textStyle),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('Facebook');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Facebook',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Color(0xFF01579B),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final guestContinue = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Wana Skip login?',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('guest');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Click here!',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                  color: Color(0xBB009388),
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        background,
        greenOpacity,
        new SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                logo,
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                description,
                SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                button('Create an account', () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                  );
                }),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                button('Sign In', () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
                  );
                }),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                separator,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                guestContinue,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                separator,
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                signWith,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

```css
//Login Page UI code is below:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:interview/signup.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('Hello',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('There',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.teal[800])),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'EMAIL',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.grey),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.grey),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                          obscureText: true,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Text(
                              'Forgot Password?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.teal[800],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            shadowColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                            color: Colors.teal[500],
                            elevation: 7.0,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'LOGIN',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      ],
                    )),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'New Here ?',
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Register',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal[800],
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                 Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Continue as Guest!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal[800],
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

```html
//Signup Page UI Code is below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(190.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.teal),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'First Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Last Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'EMAIL',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'PASSWORD ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                            color: Colors.teal,
                            elevation: 7.0,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'SIGNUP',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  width: 1.0),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Go Back',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              
            ]));
  }
}
```

I need help to create a function, which can take values entered in my signup page and complete the registration, also an email validation link is to be added.
Also, I need help in creating a function to login by calling the RESTFUL API.
The login should establish a session and if the user returns to the App after he has logged in, he should be directed to the home page by skipping the Splash and Login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use shared preferences to keep user logged in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

First you should put two controllers for mail and password inputs

`final _mailController = TextEditingController();`

`final _passController = TextEditingController();`

then at each Text filed add `controller: _passController` and same goes for mail.

To user the restful API you have to call the API in `onTap()` of the log in button.
here's an example:

```
onTap: () async {
           String urL ="Here put your API Link"
           //Example: "https://Mywebsite/api/values/" +_mailController.text +"/" + _passController.text;
           var reponse = await http.get(urL,
           headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
           var data = json.decode(reponse.body);
}
```

In `data` should be what you return from the API.
also you have to `import 'dart:convert';` and `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

In case the response is OK then you need to save this in the Shared preferences.
This answer will help you a lot in this: [How to use shared preferences to keep user logged in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Splash Screen UI Code:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:interview/myhomepage.dart';
import 'package:interview/signup.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
);

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      vsync: this,
    );

    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  final background = Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.jpg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
  final greenOpacity = Container(
    color: Color(0xAA72F1CF),
  );

  Widget button(String lable, Function onTap) {
    return new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: new SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, -0.6), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(controller),
        child: Material(
          color: Color(0xBB00D699),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            splashColor: Colors.white24,
            highlightColor: Colors.white10,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  lable,
                  style: textStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

    final logo = new ScaleTransition(
      scale: animation,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/logo.png',
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
      ),
    );

    final description = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: new SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, -0.8), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(controller),
        child: Text(
          'The interviewee social network.',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: textStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final separator = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              'OR',
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          ),
          Container(width: 20.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final signWith = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Sign in with',
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('google');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Google',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Color(0xFFE65100),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(' or', style: textStyle),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('Facebook');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Facebook',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Color(0xFF01579B),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final guestContinue = new FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Wana Skip login?',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('guest');
            },
            child: Text(
              ' Click here!',
              style: textStyle.copyWith(
                  color: Color(0xBB009388),
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        background,
        greenOpacity,
        new SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                logo,
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                description,
                SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                button('Create an account', () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                  );
                }),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                button('Sign In', () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
                  );
                }),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                separator,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                guestContinue,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                separator,
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                signWith,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

```css
//Login Page UI code is below:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:interview/signup.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('Hello',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('There',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text('.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 80.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.teal[800])),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'EMAIL',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.grey),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.grey),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                          obscureText: true,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Text(
                              'Forgot Password?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.teal[800],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            shadowColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                            color: Colors.teal[500],
                            elevation: 7.0,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'LOGIN',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      ],
                    )),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'New Here ?',
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Register',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal[800],
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                 Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Continue as Guest!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal[800],
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

```html
//Signup Page UI Code is below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(190.0, 125.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.teal),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'First Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Last Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'EMAIL',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'PASSWORD ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                            color: Colors.teal,
                            elevation: 7.0,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'SIGNUP',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  width: 1.0),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Go Back',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              
            ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.