# Flutter Session stores data but can't make decisions based off it

Tags: flutter, session, session-management, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm using [FlutterSession](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session) to store phone number/email (based on user's choice) as a method of logging into the app. The session works fine in case of email but when I store and retrieve phone number, it shows me the snapshot has no data.

This is the method where I'm setting the session value for the phone number:

```
void phoneSignIn() async {
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.length < 10) {
      print('Please enter a valid phone number!');
    }
    else {
      await fillers.session.set("phoneNum", phoneNumber);
      print('Phone number is: '+ phoneNumber);
      setState(() {
        phoneSignedIn = true;
      });
      var sessionCheck = await fillers.session.get("phoneNum");
      print("Session value: $sessionCheck");
      print(phoneSignedIn);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OnboardOne()));
    }
  }
```

In the above code, I've made sure using print statements that the session is storing phone number value and also that the phoneSignedIn bool is set to true.

This is the method where I'm setting session value for email:

```
void signIn() async {
    response = await Dio().post(url,
      data: {
        "email": emailVal,
        "password": passwordVal
      }
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await fillers.session.set('email', emailVal);
      await fillers.session.set('password', passwordVal);
      print('Sign In successful!');
      print('Email: $emailVal');
      print('Password: $passwordVal');
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OnboardOne()));
    }
    else 
    {
      print('Exited with statuscode ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Email: $emailVal');
      print('Password: $passwordVal');
    }
  }
```

This is my firstpage where I decide on which page to go based on whether the user has logged in or not:

```
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: phoneSignedIn ? session.get("phoneNum") : session.get('email'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData ? Dashboard() : SignUpIn();
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've done nothing different in the email sign in (except using a backend api to auth the email). Ultimately, I'm using the same technique to store both the email and phone number. But when I've signed in using phone number and then reopen the app, the app goes to the SignUpIn() page, when it should actually go to the Dashboard() page.
Also, on the dashboard, there's a button "Sign Out", on pressing which, the session values are cleared.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you please share the code as Gist or in Github?