# Provider is not working when navigate to new screen

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I implemented Authentication by provider

The problem is when is the first time myHomeCalss is notified that the user is Authenticated by dont return the correctPage  (MainGui)

SplashPages is page with a button continue, and push the login page ,

The Login page is pushed outside of costumer

[image]

but when I dont pass in the SplashPages is worked perfectyl

any adea please

//splash page

```
ContinueButton(
                  onPressed:  (){

                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) =>
                              ListenableProvider.value(
                                value: yourModel,
                                child: LoginPage(),
                              ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                )
```

//main

```
void main() async {
      setupLocator();
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await firebase_core.Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthenticationService()),
          ],
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      );
    }
```

//My app

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHome(),
        builder: (context, child) => Navigator(
              key: locator<DialogService>().dialogNavigationKey,
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DialogManager(child: child)),
            ));
  }
}
```

MyHome

```
 Class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: startTime(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot2) {
                if (snapshot2.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot2.data) {
                    return SplashPages();
                  } else {
                    return Consumer<AuthenticationService>(builder: (_, auth, __) {
                      if (auth.currentUserr == null) {
                        return LoginPage();
                      } else {
                        return FutureBuilder(
                            future: auth.populateCurrentUser(auth.currentUserr),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (auth.currentUserr.emailVerified) {
                                  return MainGui();
                                } else {
                                  return ValidationMailPage(
                                    email: auth.currentUserr.email,
                                  );
                                }
                              } else
                                return Container(
                                    //     child: Center(
                                    //         child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                                    //   color: Colors.white,
                                    //   size: 50.0,
                                    // ))
                                    );
                            });
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }
```

Comment: So whats the problem that you are facing?

Comment: the problem is when passing to splashes-> Login (autheniticated its worked but its not redirect again to MainGui°

Comment: So after the login is done it doesn't navigate to home page?

Comment: yes thas it espacilly when i pass by splash pages

Comment: the image is show that loginPage is outside of consumer

Comment: Why do you need a provider in this case? Can't you use a SharedPref to store the first time loing and always check if the user is authenticated or not and based on that showing the login or home page?

Comment: yes thats what i did , the senario, is when isthefirt instalation = > splashesPages- push LoginVien, if is logged , MainGui , if isNOt the firstInslation => LoginPage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231411/discussion-between-sisir-and-anna).

Comment: As discussed, you can change your design as suggested in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter/54382116#54382116

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using SharedPreferences, in which you will store the user (or maybe just the token), and then check in main if there is a token/user stored there before rendering the app; if there is a token you log in and then push to the homepage, if not you navigate directly to the login page.

SharedPrefenreces is persisted data storage that persists even if you restart the app, but Provider is a state management solution that doesn't persist between app restarts.

Here is the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin you may use.

Comment: thanks for comment but, i want the solution with provider :)

Comment: you can't do that, provider will never persist the state. Provider will be the layer between SharedPreferences and your UI. I mean, Provider will get the data from SharedPreferences and then provide it to your UI.