# how to save my login details when I check remember me. -flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to save my login details when I click remember me button. and next time I login in to the system I don't want to add details again. how can I do this. You can find my login screen full code from here. all the API integrations are completed. [login full code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17EUcaXB2N0sjALU6XhwTmYyJ2wvF-bPFzJHVK9DcyDA/edit?usp=sharing)

```
remberMeCheckBox() {
      return CheckboxListTile(
        checkColor: textGrey,
        activeColor: textGrey,
        value: false,
        onChanged: (value) {},
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
        title: Text(
          "Remember Me",
          style: TextStyle(color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use shared preferences to keep user logged in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377188/how-to-use-shared-preferences-to-keep-user-logged-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package named `shared_preferences`. If you want to save the data just use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharePreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("yourKeyForStringHere",yourStringHere);
```

After that it will store your values in local storage
if you want to extract it just type

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.getString("yourKeyForStringHere");
```

You can set it for every data type like int string bool aur lists etc.

Comment: FlutterSecureStorage should be used instead of that for using important credentials!

Answer (score 1):

shared_preferences DOES NOT work! it works on the local host while debugging the web app but throws an uncaught error while trying to use its functionalities from an actual device.

if you want to remember a device has logged in or not, to show the signup or home page accordingly, use the device's ID and other info in the HTTP request header.

https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus